# Stumped on Semaphore algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, semaphore

I was assigned a program to correctly use `wait()` and `signal()` functions as semaphores. The task is to "metaphorically" create a diamond formation.
On paper, it would look like this in an hierarchical fashion

```
    08
  06  07  
03  04  05
  01  02
    00

Thread #08 cannot join the diamond until threads #06 and #07 are both in position.
Thread #07 cannot join until threads #04 and #05 are both in position.
Thread #06 cannot join until threads #03 and #04 are both in position. and so on...
```

So far, this is my work

**DIAMOND.CPP**

```
/*  Diamond Formation Program   */

#include <iostream>
#include <sched.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "sem.h"

#define THREAD_COUNT 9

using namespace std;

extern sim_semaphore create_sim_sem(int) ;
extern void wait_sem (sim_semaphore) ;
extern void signal_sem (sim_semaphore) ;

      /* For technical reasons, we use the pthread mutex below,
         instead of a semaphore, to lock the screen for output.  Don't
         change this.  */

pthread_mutex_t stdoutLock ;

     /* Here (between the lines) declare whatever shared
        variables you need for
        synchronization - such as semaphores, flags, counters,
        and so forth. Variables declared here will be visible
        to (shared by) all the threads in the task. */
   /* HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH */
sim_semaphore tCount[THREAD_COUNT] ;

//declare array semaphore
   /* HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH */

     /* These are global variable to represent threads created
        dynamically. */
pthread_t thr[THREAD_COUNT] ;

    /* This is included to facilitate adding random delays in the code
       -- as a debugging aid. */
extern long random(void);

   /* This can be changed to 1, but the resulting diagnostic output
      will probably seem excessive. */
int checking = 0 ;

     /* A data type - a struct (class) with an int field to represent
        a thread ID. */
struct threadIdType
{
  int id ;
};

/* ################################################## */
/*                         init                       */
/* ################################################## */
void init()
{
  int index ;

      /* This code initializes special mutex lock for screen output.
         Just leave this alone. */
  if ( 0!=pthread_mutex_init(&stdoutLock, NULL) )
  {  cout << "MUTEX INITIALIZATION FAILURE!" << endl ;
     exit(-1) ;}

    /* Between the lines below, insert the code you want to
       initialize the shared variables you are using for
       synchronization - like semaphores, flags,
       counters, and so forth. */
   /* HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH */

    for (index=0; index<THREAD_COUNT; index++) tCount[index] = create_sim_sem(1) ;

//best use a for-loop for this to initialize
   /* HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH */

       /* This initializes a random number generator */
  srandom(time((time_t *) 0));
}

/* ################################################## */
/*                     rand_delay                     */
/* ################################################## */
void rand_delay(int max)
{
  int m_delay, j ;
  m_delay = (int) random()%max ;
  for (j=0; j<m_delay; j++) sched_yield();
}

/* ################################################## */
/*                childMessage                        */
/* ################################################## */
void childMessage (int ID)
{
   pthread_mutex_lock(&stdoutLock) ;
   cout << "Child # " << ID
        << " is now in position.\n" ;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&stdoutLock) ;
}

/* ################################################## */
/*                        child                       */
/* ################################################## */

void * child(void * idPtr)
{
       /* This is just a change of data type for convenience.  Now
          'me' is the number of the child.  Children have numbers from
          0 to 8. */
   int me = ((threadIdType *) (idPtr))->id, temp ;

       /* Delay code inserted here to magnify the chances that child
          threads will delay each other.  The student
          completing the program should think of more ways to insert
          random delays that are likely to 'stress test' the program. */

   rand_delay(100) ;

       /* You need to put some of the synchronization code
          between the lines, before the statement further down,
          where the child process declares it has
          put itself into position. */

   /* HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH */
    wait_sem (tCount[me*2+1]) ;
    wait_sem (tCount[me*2+2]) ;
   /* HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH */

   childMessage(me) ;  // get into position

      /* Depending on what amount of synchronization code you placed
         earlier in this function, you may need some more between
         these lines, before the child exits (and 'dies'). */

   /* HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH */
    if (me==0) {
        signal_sem (tCount[0]);
   }
//signal when done
   /* HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH */

   pthread_exit ((void *)0) ;
}

/* ################################################## */
/*                       mother                       */
/* ################################################## */

/* The mother spawns child threads and then waits for
   them all to finish.  The mother's waiting has to be
   implemented as part of the overall protocol - using
   the sim_semaphore data type. */

void mother()
{
   int i;

       /* This is a pointer to a struct (class) that contains an int
          field - it is a convenient data type to use as the parameter
          to the child function.  */
   threadIdType * idPtr ;

        /* Create child threads numbered 1 through 8.  The mother
           will play the role of position #9 */

   pthread_mutex_lock(&stdoutLock) ;
   cout << "Mother Begins Spawning Threads.\n"   << endl ;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&stdoutLock) ;

   for (i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT ; i++)
   {
      idPtr = new threadIdType ; /* allocate memory for struct */
      idPtr->id = i ;  /* records current index as the child's ID */

         /* The call below is what actually creates the child thread
            and passes a pointer to the struct 'idPtr' as the
            parameter to the child function. */

      if ( 0!=pthread_create(&thr[i], NULL, child, (void *) idPtr) )
      {  pthread_mutex_lock(&stdoutLock) ; /* 'error out' code here */
         cout << "THREAD CREATION FAILURE!" << endl ;
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&stdoutLock) ;
         exit(-1) ; }

         /* The call to pthread_detach() below marks a child
            thread as 'detached' so that the system will not
            expect the parent to 'join' (wait for) it. */

      if (0!=pthread_detach(thr[i]))
      {  pthread_mutex_lock(&stdoutLock) ;/* 'error out' code here */
         cout << "THREAD DETACHMENT FAILURE!" << endl ;
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&stdoutLock) ;
         exit(-1) ;}
   }

   pthread_mutex_lock(&stdoutLock) ;
   cout << "Mother Finishes Spawning Threads.\n"   << endl ;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&stdoutLock) ;

      /* Some protocol code is needed here to make the mother behave
         correctly - she is not supposed to return to main and
         exit until all the children have taken their positions. */

      /* HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH */
   for (i=1; i<THREAD_COUNT; i++) //mother checks
   wait_sem (tCount[i]) ;
//wait

   for (i=1; i<THREAD_COUNT; i++)
   signal_sem (tCount[i]) ;
//signal
      /* HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH */

   pthread_mutex_lock(&stdoutLock) ;
   cout << "\nAll children are now in position.\n" ;
   cout << "Mother exiting ... \n\n" ;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&stdoutLock) ;
   return ;
}

/* ################################################## */
/*                         main                       */
/* ################################################## */

int main()
{

   cout << "\nWelcome to Diamond Heights!\n\n" ;

     /* This calls the function that performs initializations. */
  init();

        /* Execute the mother() function */
  mother();

  return 0 ;
}
```

I tried performing a check on the `wait_sem()` in the mother class and making her exit once all 8 children are placed. But she isn't, is something wrong with my algorithm?

What this program outputs:

```
Mother Begins Spawning Threads.

Child # 0 is now in position.
Child # 1 is now in position.
Child # 2 is now in position.
Mother Finishes Spawning Threads.

Segmentation fault
```

What I want is:

```
Mother Begins Spawning Threads.

Mother Finishes Spawning Threads.

Child # 0 is now in position.
Child # 1 is now in position.
Child # 2 is now in position.
Child # 5 is now in position.
Child # 4 is now in position.
Child # 7 is now in position.
Child # 3 is now in position.
Child # 6 is now in position.
Child # 8 is now in position.

All children are now in position.
Mother exiting ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
#define THREAD_COUNT 9
sim_semaphore tCount[THREAD_COUNT] ;
```

and your `i`th child accesses

```
wait_sem (tCount[me*2+1]) ;
wait_sem (tCount[me*2+2]) ;
```

i.e. starting with child number 4 you will access the `tCount` array out of bounds. The calculation of the element of the `tCount` array to wait on has to be different. Make sure to not access elements below 0 and above `THREAD_COUNT+1`.

Comment: OK, I'm not quite sure what you are suggesting, what is your proposed change? Does my calculation not work properly?

Comment: Well, in the beginning you state, thread 8 has to wait on 7 and 6, 7 on 4 and 5, and so on. But now your ith thread waits on threads i*2+1 and i*2+2. You have to find a better formula to model what you want. Your segfault results from the fact that the formula is wrong and you access the array out of bounds.

Comment: OK I see now. I'll try to think of an idea. Also, does my mother class correspond correctly?

Comment: Your mother could just join all threads instead of detaching them and waiting on their semaphores, but what you have now will probably work as well. But it seems there is a special treatment of semaphore 0 both in the child and the mother, I'm not sure that's correct.

Comment: I'm having trouble coming up with a replacement formula, do you have an idea?

Comment: What special treatment of semaphore 0 are you referring to?

Comment: In the child: `if (me==0) { signal_sem (tCount[0]); }`. And in the mother, your loops concerning the semaphores start at 1.

Comment: I changed my child algorithm to just `wait_sem (tCount[me] ;` and it produces almost what I want, but it can't seem to exit. Any thoughts?